# Equivalence of protocol.http of openlayers 2 to openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, features

I am new to openlayers. I have following code in openlayers 2.

```
for (var i=0;i<wfslayers.length;i++) {
    var object=wfslayers[i];
    var url="/"+object.resourcelocation+"/wfs?token="+object.token+"&layer="+object.name;
    var legendUrl="/"+object.resourcelocation+"/wms?token="+object.token+"&layer="+object.name;

    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(object.name, { 
        layerid: object.label_text,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:"+object.srid), 
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()], 
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({ 
            url: url, 
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON() ,
            geometryName: object.geometry_name
        }),
        legendUrl:legendUrl,
        isBaseLayer: false, 
        "visibility": false,
        "chkboxRef":object.chkboxRef
        },{
        "chkboxRef":object.chkboxRef
        }); 
        wfscatalog.push(layer);
    }
```

I tried to convert it to openlayers 3. Following is my code. But I need help in the conversion of protocol part and strategies part. Please help.

```
for (var i=0;i<wfslayers.length;i++) {
    var object=wfslayers[i];
    var url="/"+object.resourcelocation+"/wfs?token="+object.token+"&layer="+object.name;
    var legendUrl="/"+object.resourcelocation+"/wms?token="+object.token+"&layer="+object.name;

    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        projection: "EPSG:"+object.srid,
        isBaseLayer: false,
        visible:false
      });
      layer.layerid=object.label_text;
      layer.legendUrl=legendUrl;
      layer.chkboxRef=object.chkboxRef;

     wfscatalog.push(layer);
    }
```

Comment: Any answer or comment?

Comment: @juminet Can you answer?

Comment: @erilem Please answer